# how to handle connection timeouts while calling server methods

Tags: node.js, meteor, error-handling, connection-timeout

How to handle connection timeouts with serverside methods? I use meteor most of the time for mobile ios/android apps (no webapps, real appstore versions) and mobile users have often connection timeouts. So sometimes they get no feedback when they tab a button because the connection is just too bad.

e.g. I have a serverside-**only** method to insert a new `document` with a special `text` in the collection `MyTextCollection`

so my methods looks like something like this

```
Meteor.methods({
    addTextToMyTextCollection: function(text) {
        //some input checks and error stuff here 
        //if something is wrong It will throw new Error.

        ...

        //everything is fine so insert text into collection
        MyTextCollection.insert({text:text});

        return someResult
    }
});
```

on the clientside I would call

```
Meteor.call("addTextToMyTextCollection", myTextILikeToStore, function(error, result){
  if (error) {
    // I have an error 
  else {
    // I have a result
  }
});
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to handle a bad wifi/4G etc connection here to give some feedback for the users to wait (like its loading please wait or your connection is broken try again). The Method is just returning an `Error` when there is something wrong with my `permission` or with my `text` I used as a Parameter. Otherwise its returning me the `result`.

Is it possible to limit the time on the clientside to throw an Error after the method call is not returning anything?

What happens when my device was able to make a call to the `addTextToMyTextCollection` method but the connection was broken when receiving the result/error? How can I handle this for my UI ?

I dont like optimistic UI (method call on server/clientside) because its not always the result that was expected (e.g. asking for server only information that the client can´t know)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a global autorun block that monitors the connection status via [Meteor.status](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_status). You can use that to display an error message when the connection is lost.

Comment: this is what I´m doing right now but this is not fixing my problem with a slow connection. the connection status flag (e.g.  stored in a session var) is just saying: OK I´m connected with the server, I´m connecting right now or the connection broken. This is just a "YES" or "NO" solution but not a "damn your connection is so slow"-fix